# Terminal command equivalent of PHP implode when combining lines

Tags: bash, awk, terminal

I have a couple of lines and want to group the line into 5 and then implode it for MySQL `IN ()` query.

I have made it out until this

```
awk '{ printf "%s", $0; if (NR % 5 == 0) print ""; else printf " " }
```

For example, I want these lines below

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

to be

```
1,2,3,4,5
6
```

If I use this

```
awk '{ printf "%s", $0; if (NR % 5 == 0) print ""; else printf "," }
```

Then the output will have `,` in the trailing line if all the lines are not divisible by 5

**UPDATE**

Previous title is awk instead of bash, but turns out there is more simpler solution than awk. My goal is to do something like this

```
$seq 12 | pr -7ats, | xargs -I X echo "SELECT * FROM Table IN (X)" #or execute mysql
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id IN (8,9,10,11,12)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pr` is the tool for this

```
$ seq 6 | pr -5ats,
1,2,3,4,5
6

$ seq 18 | pr -5ats, 
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15
16,17,18
```

Comment: Although I initially posted for `awk` but this one is much more suitable for my needs. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
  a[NR] = $0
}
END {
  for (b in a) {
    printf a[b] (b % 5 && b != NR ? "," : RS)
  }
}
```

Or one liner:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} END {for (b in a) printf a[b] (b%5 && b!=NR ? "," : RS)}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
awk 'NR%5==0{print s","$0; s=""; next} {if (length(s)>0){ s=s","$0 } else s=$0} END {print s}'
```

Test it:

```
$ seq 1 6 | awk 'NR%5==0{print s","$0; s=""; next} {if (length(s)>0){ s=s","$0 } else s=$0} END {print s}'
1,2,3,4,5
6
$ seq 1 12 | awk 'NR%5==0{print s","$0; s=""; next} {if (length(s)>0){ s=s","$0 } else s=$0} END {print s}'
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
11,12
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not a single process `awk` command, you can even use `paste` and `sed` combination like this:

```
$ cat file 
1
2
3
4
5
6
$ paste - - - - - -d , < file | sed 's/,\+$//'
1,2,3,4,5
6
$ seq 1 12 > file 
$ cat file 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
$ paste - - - - - -d , < file | sed 's/,\+$//'
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
11,12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
seq 16 |awk '{printf NR%5 ? (NR % 5 ==1 ? $0 : ","$0) : ","$0"\n";}'
#output:
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15
16
```

Comment: This does not emit trailing newline

Comment: i am sorry，can you give me an example？