# Convert data format using awk?

Tags: awk

There is a file which contains data in a `'n*1'` format:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Is there any way to convert it to a `'n*3'` format like:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

via `awk` rather than using `for loop` ?

Really no idea about this..Any help or key word is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Terminal command equivalent of PHP implode when combining lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40297297/terminal-command-equivalent-of-php-implode-when-combining-lines)

Comment: imo, `pr` is best suited for this as mentioned in duplicate... also, please add your own efforts to question while asking.. see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using awk

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s",$0,(NR%3==0?ORS:",")}' File
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

The command `printf "%s%s",$0,(NR%3==0?ORS:",")` tells awk to print two strings.  The first is `$0` which is the current line.  The second string is `NR%3==0?ORS:","` which is either ORS the output record separator (if the line number is a multiple of three) or else `,` for all other line numbers.

#### Using sed

```
$ sed 'N;N;s/\n/,/g' File
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

By default, sed reads in each line from the file one by one.  `N` tells sed to read in another line, appending the line to the current one, separated by a newline.  `N;N` tells sed to do that twice so that we have a total of three lines in the pattern space.  `s/\n/,/g` tells sed to replace those two separator newlines with commas.  The result is then printed.

The above assumes that we are using GNU sed.  With minor modifications, this can be made to work with BSD/OSX sed.

Answer (score 2):

The most simple one - **`paste`** command:

```
paste -d, - - - <file
```

The output:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

Answer (score 1):

Following may help you on same.

```
xargs -n3  <  Input_file | sed 's/ /,/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk 'NR%3==0{print;next}{printf "%s,",$0}' file
```

or decomposed :

```
NR%3==0           # condition, modulo 3 == 0
{print;next}      # then print and skip to the first line
{printf "%s,",$0} # printf to not print newlines but current int + ,
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{ORS=(NR%3?",":RS)}1' file
1,2,3
4,5,6
```